# Philips 202el only shows display if both vga and dvi are connected to my cpu

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi, vga, dvi

This is really weird since I never encountered such trouble like this. So my display is connected to video card which is an ATI HD Radeon 4650. My VGA ports and cable are okay as well as my DVI ports and cable. Btw, my DVI cable is not really a DVI but DVI-HDMI. DVI goes to my monitor and HDMI goes to my video card. Last night, my monitor started popping out the menus automatically and I can't stop it. That happened before like 3 times. So I restarted my PC and the display won't come out. I tried inserting the VGA but nothing happened but when I plugged both VGA and DVI-HDMI cables, it worked. However, the display only works if both are plugged. I just want to get back to VGA. Anyone?